# Best way to learn MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm familiar and have worked with Hive, Pig, HBase. I have also gone through the Hadoop Definitive guide. I am familiar with core java, MapReduce architecture and MapReduce internals. However, I don't have any hands on experience in MapReduce and I need to learn MapReduce in terms of practical scenarios. Is there any book or link which you would recommend? I would appreciate any help or suggestions. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this book. This contains different mapreduce scenarios and code snippets.
[MapReduce Patterns](http://www.amazon.in/MapReduce-Design-Patterns-Effective-Algorithms-ebook/dp/B00AB61JMQ)