# In search of more Hadoop examples

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I have setup hadoop on my pc and ran my first map-red program of wordcount. I am searching where and what kind of other case studies I can get into. where can I get some sample code?

I have got some jar file from https://code.google.com/p/hadoop-map-reduce-examples/downloads/list?can=1&q=
but unable figure out what are these jars for?

Comment: You can use this: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31981747/2254048)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are very good tutorials, with explained code:

- https://hadooptutorial.wikispaces.com/Example+programs
- https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/

Comment: also the Hadoop the definitive guide by Orielly is also a good grab